# how to handle click event in jquery

Tags: jquery, solr, jsonp

I want to parse solr JSON object and want to display it in a web page. I used jQuery getJson for it.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">



         $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
        var q=getquerystring() ;

        $.getJSON("http://192.168.1.9:8983/solr/db/select/?wt=json&q="+q+"&json.wrf=?", function(result){
        alert("hello");

                $.each(result.response.docs, function(i,item){
                    alert(result.response.docs);
                    alert(item.UID_PK);
                });
        });
        });
        });

function getquerystring() {
  var form = document.forms['f1'];
  var query = form.query.value;
  qstr = escape(query);

  return qstr;
}

</script>

</head>

<body>
 <form name="f1" >
  <p>query: <input name="query" type="text">  
 <!-- <input value="Go" type="submit">-->
  <button id="submit">Click Me</button></p>
 <div id="result"></div>
<!--<p/><pre>Raw JSON String: <div id="raw"></div></pre>-->
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

When I use `$("#c2").click(function()` then it does not enter in `$.getJSON()` and when i remove `$("#c2").click(function()` from the code it run fine. Why is so please explain. because I want to get data from a text box on onclickevent and then display response.

Comment: do you have an element with id c2?

Comment: Also, do you have a function called getquerystring?  A handy place to debug any sort of javascript error would be to use some sort of developer tool. Firebug for Firefox is fantastic, though most browsers come with a console will suffice.

Comment: and i there a c2 present on domready or is it populated afterwards. have you tried to bind the click using `live`?

Comment: element is this :                                              <form name="f1" >
  <p>query: <input name="query" type="text">  
 <!-- <input value="Go" type="submit">-->
  <button id="c2">Click Me</button></p>
  
<div id="result"></div>
<!--<p/><pre>Raw JSON String: <div id="raw"></div></pre>-->
</form>

Comment: Javascript is case sensitive.  If your function is called getQuerystring, you need to call getQuerystring()

Comment: I'd still highly advise using a debugging tool like Firebug, as it will tell you exactly what line is causes the problem and what sort of problem it is.

Comment: @naveen,@Jeff :yes i have a function getQuerystring which is returning the text entered in text box

Comment: @jeff: getqueryfunction() is working fine. and i do not know how can i use firebug to debug javascript

Comment: @Romi Visit http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: @jeff: it is showing this error (types || "").split is not a function in jquey.1.5.2.js, and i am not getting what it is all about

Comment: @Romi Sorry, I'm not sure why you're getting that error.  Perhaps you could try using the newest version of jQuery (1.6.1), just in case?

Comment: Also, are you using any other javascript plugins besides jQuery?  Sometimes different JS libraries will conflict with each other.

Comment: Jeff: I used jquery.1.6.2 too and other than this i am not using any other plugins

Answer (score 0):

use `delegate`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $("#c2").delegate('click',function(){
                var q=getquerystring() ;

                $.getJSON("http://192.168.1.9:8983/solr/db/select/?wt=json&q="+q+"&json.wrf=?", function(result){
                    $.each(result.response.docs, function(i,item){
                        alert(result.response.docs);
                        alert(item.UID_PK);
                    });
                });
            });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query string could be to blame. You should escape reserved URI characters. Try changing this to:

```
var getValues = { wt: 'json', q: q, 'json.wrf': '?' };

$.getJSON("http://192.168.1.9:8983/solr/db/select/", getValues, function(result){
```

jQuery will automatically convert the object to a query string AND escape bad characters. I assume here that your `getquerystring` function isn't to blame.

Comment: Gary Green : My problem is it is not entering in $.getJSON() when i use $("#c2").click(function() otherwise it is working fine

Comment: @Romi your code looks fine, so there's something in `getquerystring()` which your not showing us, or it's an event handling/dispatching/bubbling issue, again, this will be hard to tell without seeing more of your HTML and code. Can you do some debugging i.e. after `.click(function() {` put `alert('hi');` just to see if the click function fires.

Comment: getqueryfunction is doing fine as it is supposed to. and i pit alert("hi") after .click(function(){ then it got a alert "hi" but after this it does not enter in getJSON() function.

Comment: i just  posted my whole file in my post please look at this

Comment: It's strange how your building this query string like that, you really don't need to use getquerystring at all. I suggest you utilise `.serialize` instead. If you need `json.wrf` and `wt` as part of the query string then put these as hidden input elements in your form. `<input type="hidden" name="json.wrf" value="?"/>` then you can do `$.getJSON('http://192.168.1.9:8983/solr/db/select/', $('#f1').serialize(), function(result) ....` -- also can you put inside your `function(result)` this... `alert(JSON.toString(result));` and show the result to us